# How to hide search bar on scroll? (without UITableViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a simple UIViewController containing a UITableView and I want to hide search bar inside of navigation bar on scrolling UITableView. I found

```swift
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
```

but it does not work. Is there any way to make it work on UIViewController?

Comment: what is the scroll direction ?

Comment: where u added this

Comment: What happened issue is resolved or not ?

Answer (score 3):

> SWIFT 4 simple implementation

Add `UISearchBarDelegate` delegate to your class

Then add this function in your class

```
func showSearchBar() {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true 
    //true for hiding, false for keep showing while scrolling
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.search
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}
```

Then call the function in your `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: I love how this works. But adding this to my SearchBarDelegate just creates another search bar.

Comment: just don't add search bar from the storyboard, or remove the first line from the searchbar.

Answer (score 0):

My guesses are when you first enter the `UIViewController` the `UISearchBar` is by default hidden, considering you're using `UISearchController` and access it with a search icon or something.

For this case, iOS by default doesn't hide the `UISearchBar` and (hides it/shows it) based on your scroll direction in the `UITableView` now how to solve this .

Since there are nothing we can do to cancel this behavior but we can have some work around slightly better when a user tapes cancel we set the `UISearchController` to `nil` to remove it from the `UIViewController` and when the user tap on the search icon, we gives it a value again and show it .

> Note : This answer assuming that you implement it that way considering there is not much context nor code to in the question .

Lets get into the code .

```
 func prepareSearchController() { //function to setup the SearchBar  
    // Setup the Search Controller
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Items"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
}

   @objc func openSearch() { // when user tap on the search icon 
    prepareSearchController()
    self.navigationItem.searchController?.isActive = true
}
```

Now we conform to `UISearchBarDelegate` to access the cancel button action.

```
 func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) { // this function is available only in search bar delegate  make sure to conform to it . 
    self.navigationItem.searchController = nil 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try this approach**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
              navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
       }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
              navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
      }
}
```